# re.search becomes unresponsive

Tags: python, regex

When i run this code it doesn't print neither `'checked'` nor `'not matching'`. It stops responding completely.

```
url='http://hoswifi.bblink.cn/v3/2-fd1cc0657845832e5e1248e6539a50fa/topic/55-13950.html?from=home'

m=re.search(r'/\d-(B|(\w+){10,64})/index.html',url)
if m:
    print('checked')
else:
    print('not matching')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose we have the following script:

```
s = '1234567890'    
m = re.search(r'(\w+)*z', s)
```

Our string contains 10 digits, and does not contain `'z'`. This is intentional so that it forces `re.search` to check *all* possible combinations, otherwise it will stop on first match.

I can't calculate the number of possible combinations, since math involved is rather tricky, but here is a small demonstration on what happens when `s` gets more digits:

[image]

Time goes from roughly 1μs for a single digit `s` to 100 seconds for a 30 digit `s`, that is, 10<sup>8</sup> more time.

---

My guess is that something similar happens when you use `(\w+){10,64}`. Instead you should use `\w{10,64}`.

---

Code used for the demo:

```
import timeit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

setup = """
import re
"""    
_base_stmt = "m = re.search(r'(\w+)*z','{}')"

# (searched string becomes '1', '11', '111'...)
statements = {}
for i in range(1, 18):
    statements.update({i: _base_stmt.format('1'*i)})

# Creates x, y values
x = []
y = []
for i in sorted(statements):
    x.append(i)
    y.append(timeit.timeit(statements[i], setup, number=1))

# Plot
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xlabel('string length')
plt.ylabel('time(sec)')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score -1):

This is right.

' \w+{10,64} ' is wrong,\w+ should not with '+'

```
   url='http://hoswifi.bblink.cn/v3/2-fd1cc0657845832e5e1248e6539a50fa/topic/55-13950.html?from=home'
m=re.search(r'/\d-(B|\w{10,64})/index.html',url)
if m:
    print('checked')
else:
    print('not matching')
```